# $u_p=u_{p-1}p+1.2. \cdots p$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I need some help with this exercise:

Let be $u_0,u_1,\cdots,u_n$, numbers such that $u_0$ is know and the rest unknow

We know that : $u_1=u_0+1  ,   u_2=2u_1+1.2  \  , u_3=3u_1+1.2.3 $
and :
$ u_p=pu_{p-1}+1.2 \cdots p \\ $

Show that : $u_n=(u_o+n)1.2.\cdots n$

If i say that : $v_1=1, v_2=2v_1 , v_n=nv_{n-1}$

I say that : $u_n=u_o1.2 \cdots n +1.2 \cdots n (v_1 + (n-1)) $

But maybe i say nothing when i say that,so i need some help guys

Thank you for your interest

This exercice is from tannery lesson on arithmetic (https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k99498n/f93.item.zoom)

Comment: "$u_n=(u_o+n)1.2.\cdots p$" $\;-\;$ Guess that last $\,p\,$ should be an $\,n\,$ instead. Hint: $\, u_p = p u_{p-1}+ 1\cdot2 \cdot  \text{...} \cdot p$ $\displaystyle \iff \frac{u_p}{p!} = \frac{u_{p-1}}{(p-1)!}+1\,$.

Comment: It could as well be the primorial. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

Denote $1 \cdot 2 \cdots n = n! $. Then you see that
$$\frac{u_n}{n!} = \frac{u_{n-1}}{(n-1)!} + 1$$

Now take $a_k = \frac{u_k}{k!}$ then we have $$a_k - a_{k-1} = 1$$ for all naturals $k$.

See that $(a_n - a_{n-1}) + (a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} ) + \ldots + (a_2 - a_1) + (a_1 -a _ 0) = \underbrace{1+1+\ldots + 1}_{n \, \text{times}} = n$

So we have $a_n - a_0 = n$

Can you conclude now?